# C# app not compiling correctly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to get my C# Web Application in VS 2008 Professional to compile.  I have 2 projects in one solution.  The first project, PowerMeter has an App_Code folder with namespace Inov.PowerMeter and the associated .aspx.cs files in the app reference it by using Inov.PowerMeter;.  This code compiles fine and builds the powermeter.dll correctly.  I have a second project called QuickMeter.  The app_code for this creates a namespace Inov.Quickmeter and the aspx.cs files reference it correctly.  But this doesn't compile.

The aspx.cs files can't see the namespace.  Do I have to set this "build action" to compile? Where is it?

Thanks!

Comment: what error does it give you? The asp.net proj should reference the dll project..

Comment: What is the specific compiler error?

Comment: Are those projects "Web Application" or "Web Site" ?

Comment: It gives a missing assembly error.  Which will work if I add the quickmeter.dll in, but I want it to build the quickmeter.dll for me from scratch.  It does this correctly for the powermeter.dll.  There is no powermeter.dll reference, but when I build it, it generates one correctly.

Comment: +1 to Henk... if both are Web App projects, it should work just fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you add a reference to the first project in your second project?  In the second project go to References then right click and select Add Reference

Comment: and create a Project Reference; don't browse to the /bin folder!